# Unable to draw single particle effect at two places

Tags: libgdx, particle-system

I am using Libgdx ParticleEffect to draw a fire particle effect .

The issue I have is that when I try to render a ParticleEffect at two different locations within single game loop, only the last draw call has the effect drawn on screen. I update the Particle effect only once per game loop but set its position to two distinct locations and draw it. Is this a trivial problem with Libgdx ParticleEffect.

```
ParticleEffect effect = new PartcleEffect();
effect.load(gdx.files.internal("data/effect.particle"),atlas,"");
effect.start();
```

in render :

```
effect.update(deltaTime);

effect.setPosition(x1,y1);
effect.draw(batch);

effect.setPosition(x2,y2);
effect.draw(batch);
```

Comment: If you remove/comment the first draw (or even better switch them), will the second work properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need two particle effect generator.
One for each instance.